# C++: While Loop won't break

Tags: c++

we just had an exercise at school and one part of it is to check, if a given EAN (European Article Number) is valid.

I wrote a function for it, but when I am using the while-loop, it won't go out of the loop. Here's the code:

```
bool checkEan13(unsigned int code[])
{
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    int sum;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i += 2)
    {
        sum1 += code[i];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i += 2)
    {
        sum2 += code[i];
    }

    sum2 *= 3;
    sum = sum1 + sum2;

    int difference;
    int nextNumber = sum;

    while (!nextNumber % 10 == 0)
    {
        nextNumber++;

        //if (nextNumber % 10 == 0)        <-- it works, when I put in this
        //{                                <--
        //  break;                         <--
        //}                                <--
    }

    difference = nextNumber - sum;

    if (difference == code[12])
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, it works, when I do a check with an if-statement, but why does it not work without it? Shouldn't the statement of the while-loop be invaild, if "nextNumber" is e.g. 50?

Thanks!

Comment: the `!` has higher precedence than the equality operator `%` see the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Operator precedence, anybody? That's why I *always* put parenthesis in there. I might *think* I got it right, but the parenthesis make sure the compiler and I agree on what I meant.

Comment: If C++ did not have the nasty habit of implicitly converting  `bool`to `int`, they compiler could have flagged this as an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). `!` has a higher precedence then `%` so your condition is actually evaluated as

```
(!nextNumber) % 10 == 0
```

So if `nextNumber` is a non 0 value then (!nextNumber) if false or 0 and `0 % 10` is 0

To fix it you can use

```
!(nextNumber % 10 == 0)
```

Which will check if `nextNumber % 10` is equal to `0` and return the opposite of that check.

Of course as [Marc van Leeuwen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1436796/marc-van-leeuwen) pointed out we could simply write

```
nextNumber % 10 != 0
```

which does the exact same things and now we no longer have to worry about the operator precedence.

Comment: Writing instead `nextNumber % 10 != 0` is both simpler and less error prone.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Excellent point.  I have added it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about operator precedence. Try with `while (!((nextNumber%10)==0))`.

Comment: One pair of parentheses is redunant: `while (!(nextNumber % 10 == 0))` would work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes true. I kept it like this to illustrate the concept of putting parenthesis for being sure.